# Parse Cloud Code - Await and return relation query

Tags: javascript, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

so I'm trying to get this cloud query function to run. Basically, I would like to get return the profile by its ID. Then using that result object, run a relation query and return the first result.

I'm not sure if I'm getting mixed up but I'm struggling on awaiting for the full query to finish before returning.

Thanks

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getLastWeightForAnimal", async (request) => {

try {

    var AnimalProfiles = Parse.Object.extend("animal_profiles");
    var query = new Parse.Query(AnimalProfiles);

    query.get(request.params.id).then((animalProfile) => {

        var AnimalWeights = animalProfile.relation("weights").query();

        AnimalWeights.descending("createdAt");

        let result = await AnimalWeights.first();
        return result;

    }, (error) => {
      // The object was not retrieved successfully.
      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        console.log("Uh Oh Inner");
        console.log("Error Inner: "+  error);
    });

} catch (e) {
    console.log("Uh Oh");
    console.log("Error: "+  e);
}


});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you return inside of a promise `.then(function(){return 'a'}) the`return 'a'`does not return the`async (request)` !

If you do

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(function(){return 'a'}) // this 'a' does not go to any parent function!
  .then(function(val){console.log(val)}) // it goes here!
```

you would see 'a' in your log, as a simple illustration.

You can switch it to async/await

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getLastWeightForAnimal", async (request) => {

  try {

    var AnimalProfiles = Parse.Object.extend("animal_profiles");
    var query = new Parse.Query(AnimalProfiles);

    var animalProfile = await query.get(request.params.id)

    var AnimalWeights = animalProfile.relation("weights").query();

    AnimalWeights.descending("createdAt");

    let result = await AnimalWeights.first();
    return result;

  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Uh Oh");
    console.log("Error: "+  e);
  }


});
```

OR simply return the promise, which since you're using `async` will automatically return the value of the promise.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getLastWeightForAnimal", async (request) => {

  try {

    var AnimalProfiles = Parse.Object.extend("animal_profiles");
    var query = new Parse.Query(AnimalProfiles);

    // note new return!!
    return query.get(request.params.id).then((animalProfile) => {

        var AnimalWeights = animalProfile.relation("weights").query();

        AnimalWeights.descending("createdAt");

        let result = await AnimalWeights.first();
        return result;

    }, (error) => {
      // The object was not retrieved successfully.
      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        console.log("Uh Oh Inner");
        console.log("Error Inner: "+  error);
    });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Uh Oh");
    console.log("Error: "+  e);
  }


});
```